# How do I print all fields for all tables in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to learn the structure of a mysql database I'm not familiar with. It's been years since I used mysql.

I'm looking for a way to print all the fields for all the tables in this database. At the moment, I'm using

```
Show Fields from <insert table name>
```

However, this slow and clunky. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see all tables of a specific database (like `mydb`), do this:

```
USE mydb
SHOW TABLES;
```

To see all fields, indexes, storage engine, table options, partition layout in `mydb.mytable`, do this:

```
USE mydb
SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname\G
```

To see all tables in all databases in bulk, here is a script:

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --triggers --no-data --all-databases"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} > MySQLSchema.sql
less MySQLSchema.sql
```

If you want to see a specific database (like `mydb`), do this:

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
DBTOSHOW=mydb
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --triggers --no-data --databases ${DBTOSHOW}"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} > MySQLSchema.sql
less MySQLSchema.sql
```

This should be the quickest way because accessing the information_schema database can be somewhat slow if there are a lot of busy InnoDB tables.

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link to the [MySQL Online Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html).  It is the goto resource for all of your MySQL questions.

To list all columns in a db, do a variation of this:

`select * from information_schema.columns order by table_schema, table_name, column_name`

Section 20 covers the Information_schema.  20.4 covers the columns table.

Comment: CAVEAT : This can take a long time if there are a lot of busy InnoDB tables. If all tables are MyISAM, this would be OK. +1 !!!

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test'`

Change the 'test' to the name of your database. It'll have to be ran as root user or as a user with permissions to read from the information_schema table.