# Django - Access pre-existing data in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models

What I'm trying to do is this: I have a csv file containing some public transport data. I want to use this in my Django app, so I imported the csv to my mySQL database. Then, I created a Django model for the table (I also compared my model against the output of `python manage.py inspectdb` to make sure it was correct. Then I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and finally `python manage.py migrate`. From what I understand (and I am new to Django, so sorry if I've missed something obvious), the table in my database should now be accessible to Django.

It's not working though. I've tried using the Django shell (`python manage.py shell`) and returning the table contents with `Stops.objects.all()`, which returns an empty set. Similarly, I was able to make a HttpResponse with the value of `Stops.objects.all()` and, though it didn't give an error, no data was returned. I've confirmed that I'm accessing the correct database in settings.py, and that the data is in fact there via mysql terminal.

I've been trying to fix this for ages, but haven't found any solutions. I think there's probably some small step I've missed out, that hopefully someone here will know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you connect to your mySQL server in Django settings? by default it use SQLight.

Comment: Yes, I am using the mysql connector and have the mysqlclient Python package installed. I was able to create tables, insert data, and return it just fine when I was practicing. The problem seems specific to data that isn't created through Django.

Comment: are you sure that name of the table where you imported csv file is the same, as what should be created with `makemigrations-migrate`?

Comment: As @Chiefir said, Django has a specific way to name tables it creates, it is `[app_name]_[table_name]`, could it be that you imported your data in a table named like `mydata`, but Django expects the table to be named `myapp_mydata`?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about that. The table in my database is called 'stops', and my Django model is called 'Stop'. Is there somewhere else I'm supposed to define the DB table the model is supposed to represent? Or does that class have to have the exact same name as the table?


It was something I considered when I was trying to fix this, but if the model was somehow not being associated with the correct table, wouldn't a new table be created when I run `makemigrations-migrate`? When I do that it works fine, and there still is just the 'stops' table in my DB.

Comment: That is a wrong way. As @kristaps noticed - Django create a specific name for each table. But also you can fix it in the `class Meta: db_table = 'stops'` in your model.

Comment: @kristaps maybe that's it! I'll try renaming the table. Just to be sure, if the model is defined in an app inside my project, then the table name should just be [app_name]_[table_name] and not [project_name][app_name]_[table_name]?

Comment: Yes, the project name will not be included in the table name

Comment: Thanks, you were both right. I just didn't understand the Django table naming conventions properly, it's fixed now. Thanks to both of you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would verify my tables are named as expected.

Using MySQL, [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859949/how-do-i-print-all-fields-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database)

```
USE mydb
SHOW TABLES;
```

I assume your django tables will be using the default naming scheme of f"{app_label}_{model}" so if your app is named "my_app" and your model is "stops" then you can expect django to be managing a table named "my_app_stops"

You can verify this with the django shell

$ ./manage.py shell

```
from my_app.models import Stops
Stops._meta.db_table
```

I hope this helps. Without more information, I can only show you how to investigate the most obvious flaw.

**EDIT**
If you do identify that this is the discrepancy, you have a couple of options:
(1) Rename your table to match Django, or
(2) Force django to look at your existing table using [a Meta class](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#table-names)

```
from django.db import models
class Stops(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'some_table_name'
```

Comment: That was it, thank you so much!!

When I ran `Stops._meta.db_table` I could see that it was looking for a table called [my_app]_stop, which of course was not the name of the table I was trying to use. I just renamed the table in mySQL and BAM, all my lovely bus-stops were there!

Thanks again, I've been at this for hours, and honestly don't think I would have got it on my own, so it's much appreciated!